# Is it possible to set the print preview margin property to "None" when using window.print()?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

Is it possible to set the print preview margin property to "None" (instead of "Default")

[image]

when using `window.print()` (not by changing it manually in the print preview) in Google Chrome? I am adding the page numbers and margins to the printable content myself with HTML and CSS, so it would be useful if the user could by default see no extra margins instead of having to find the setting and change it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not,

I had a similar problem and ended up rebuilding the page from raw data in FPDF (PHP).

http://www.fpdf.org/